# Trying to make a fetch request to a XML link with React getting CORS error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, xml, fetch

```
import './App.css';

function App() {

 fetch('https://basketball.realgm.com/rss/wiretap/0/0.xml')
.then(response => response.text())
.then(str => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
.then(data => console.log(data))

return (
<div className="App">
</div>
);
}

export default App;
```

So I am trying to do a simple fetch request to this XML link and I keep getting this Error:

Access to fetch at 'http://basketball.realgm.com/rss/wiretap/0/0.xml' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: clearly `basketball.realgm.com` doesn't want your website using it's resources *directly* in your web page - most common way to *fix* CORS is to make the request *via* your server - i.e. use your server as a *proxy* for the request

Answer (score 0):

In order to make requests to any origin other than the current one, the server must return a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with the requesting origin.

For example, a request from localhost to example.com:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

With the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost
...
```